# Applescript error -1700

Tags: applescript

```
display dialog "Play game?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} with title "Play?"
if {button returned:"No"}
end if
```

I pressed compile to pretest and this happened:

Applescript error

Can’t make {button returned:"No"} into type boolean.

Comment: What's AppleScript anyways? Looks like Visual Basic + Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set buttonChoice to (display dialog "Play game?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} with title "Play?")
if button returned of buttonChoice = "No" then
    return "no"
end if
```